# Separate Polylines in Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, maps

I'm making a system that records my birds with a GPS tracker. The data from the GPS trackers a stored in an MYSQL Database. Right now i'm trying to make a viewer like Flightrader 24 to plot the birds to see where they are.

I'm struggling with the readout of mulitple polylines.
What i'm doing is to readout every route of the birds with a for loop to gather every path by bird. But the problem is that it connects the path of bird 1 and bird 2 together I would like to seperate the paths from each other.

[Current System with paths connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65asx.png)

My code:

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      gestureHandling: 'greedy'

    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
    <?php
    echo 'var birdTracks = [';
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 99; $x++) {
        $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM route WHERE falcon_id = '$x'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
           $lat = $row['lat'];
           $lon = $row['lng'];
            echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$lat.', '.$lon.'),'; // Echo begin position
         }
       }
       echo '];';
       ?>

       var colors = ["#ff1663"];

       for (var i = 0; i < birdTracks.length ; i++) {
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: birdTracks,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: colors[i],
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 4
        });
        console.log(colors[i]);
      }

      flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
```

What i'm thinking is a solution to create multiple birdTracks arrays with a For loop. But i'm not getting it working.